# How to show a visual studio solution as if there were no solution folders.

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Ok, so this might not be a huge issue, but would be nice if one could "flatten" a visual studio solution that uses solution folders. In my opinion those should be a user setting and not a part of the general setup for everyone.

Anyway,  I read the docs so maybe I already know the answer that you cannot show a plan list of projects in your solution if someone grouped them in solution folders. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haytww03(v=vs.90).aspx

But maybe someone might have some setting or trick that could work for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the solution file and remove solution folders to see the projects in flat file structure. You can then open this solution when you need a different layout. Not great but once projects are added the solutions will always be in sync. So you will have 2 sln files, name the second one with flat in the name to recognise it .